# Keras / SciKeras Sequential Model not accepting 1d text array

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to create a Keras model that accepts a 1d text array. The first two layers of the model are an `Input` layer followed by a `TextVecotrization` layer:

```
def create_model(activation):
     model = keras.Sequential()
     model.add(layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype='string')
     model.add(layers.TextVectorization(
         output_mode='int'
     ))
...
     model.compile(...)
     return model
```

The problem is that when I pass the model to a SciKeras `KerasClassifier` object, when calling `.fit()`, the model errors out, citing that it cannot convert string to float on input.

When I build and run the model outside of a SciKeras `KerasClassifier`, everything works fine. However, somehow introducing the SciKeras object has made everything go wrong.

This breaks:

```
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Citing this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: -entry one of test data-
```

However, taking the code out of the `create_rnn_model()` function, and then calling `.fit()` on it trains the model successfully.